# Why is the C++ read bytes result different from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, byte, arrays

I have C# code below:

```
FileStream fs       = new FileStream("output.bin", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader _br    = new BinaryReader(fs);
var a               = _br.ReadByte();
var b               = _br.ReadByte();
fs.Close();
```

`a` returns `0x00` and `b` returns `0x03`.

But in my C++ code:

```
std::ifstream ifs("output.bin", std::ios::binary);;
char buf1[2];
ifs.read(buf1, 2);
```

`buf1[0]` returns `-52` and `buf1[1]` returns `-52`.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe it's a *different* output.bin file? What does a hex-dump (using an editor, not either language) show?

Comment: what is the content of first 2 bytes in output.bin ?

Comment: In the C++ code, what does ifs.gcount() return after the call to read()?

Comment: @sj0h it returns 0. Am I looking for a file not existing?

Comment: 0 means no characters read so the -52 are just junk. You'll have to check the state of ifs after line 1 to see if it was from an failure to open, as per answer of @Ozraptor

Comment: @sj0h Thanks for your answer. I've leant a lot from you comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that state of your stream in the C++ code after creation, and after the read, to be sure that the operations were successful. Ie `if (ifs) {...}` after creating the stream, and after reading it. If either operations failed, then after you are just reading uninitialised / undefined data from `buf1`.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ for examples of using ifstream properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I am very new to C++, I thought it would give me an error if reading not-existing file. The reason was the location of file.